# Joomla routing engine

Tags: joomla

I have written a custom landing page that I want to incorporate to my website.
the website is using Joomla as a CMS.
so when I type a UTL www.mysite.com/myLandingPahe.php i get a 404 becuse the Joomla ruting engine kiks in and searches for the article in the DB..

this is the skeleton of the landing page (basic contac form):

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

can I reserve an address to point to my custom PHP file ?

Is there another way that this can be achieved ?

Comment: Joomla have default com_contact compoent for contact form why you are using custom files for this? http://docs.joomla.org/Help32:Components_Contacts_Contacts

Comment: using custom files because i need custom styling for the page..

Comment: do you need custom header and footer for this page or just inside custom styling any way you can do with joomla com_contact. If you need custom styles just override Joomla com_contact http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Comment: Its a whole different page .. no header\footer

Comment: check my answer these are standard way to achieve your requirement.

Comment: Also please change your question title to something like "adding new custom page in Joomla" This will help someone else in future.

Comment: The whole point of Joomla templates is to let you custom style your page.  If you said "because I need to access a different database and use separate login credentials" it might make sense to do something separate though even there probably not.

Answer (score 0):

You have options,

**Use com_contact with Overrides**

copy the entire the `components/com_contact/view/` to your `templates/your_templates/html/com_contact/`.

Then add your custom styles with following methods inside your view page

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript('js file full path');
$doc->addStyleSheet('css path');
```

It will load your custom styles Then you have to avoid header and footer for feeling it as a different page. this can be achieved by using appending `tmpl=component` with the url .
like your contact url is `www.yourdomain.com/contact&tmpl=component`.

**Custom Page with Article**

create an article page with any name and set the alias with required url. then add the form and its required CSS within the article content. Here you required some plugin for including styles and script inside your article content like [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051).
Then in your form action will be like follows.

```
<form action = "index.php?option=com_contact&task=contact.contactinfo">...</form>
```

This stands for inside your `components/com_contact/controllers/contact.php` have a function with `contactinfo()` when the form submit you will get all the post data inside this function.

for retrieving form data use [Joomla default library](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput) like

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$name = $jinput->get('name', 'default_value', 'filter');
```

Also for sending email you can use.

```
            $mail = JFactory::getMailer();
            $mail->addRecipient($contact->email_to);
            $mail->addReplyTo(array($email, $name));
            $mail->setSender(array($mailfrom, $fromname));
            $mail->setSubject($sitename.': '.$subject);
            $mail->setBody($body);
            $sent = $mail->Send();
```

after sending you can redirect back to the page with .

```
$this->setRedirect('url','message success/failed','type of message eg: error,info');
```

after setting this you can just append `&tmpl=component` like above for avoiding header and footer

Hope it make sense..